# merge two MainWindow in QT,C++

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, model-view-controller

I am new to Qt, using version 5.4 with Visual Studio 2013 Community and OpenCV 3.0.
So I have a MainWindow class from which i can see my depth camera(Structor Sensor) with QVTKWidget, now what i want to do is to add a widget to view a typical RGB (color) camera.

I found a code to do this but with its own MainWindow
what i want is to combine them in one MainWindow

Comment: `RGBCamera` is derived from `QWidget`. You already used `QVTKWidget` (even though you don't show it for some reason), so what's the problem just adding another widget to your main window?

Comment: actually qvtkwidget is declared in ui_MainWindow.h which i didn't create but i created the ui file

Comment: The code you found is **obsolete**. Use C++ api instead of old C api (IplImage and the like)